How to get a query parameter value in a SavedStateHandle injected into a view model by a deeplink using compose navigation?
I'm trying to get the token value of the following link (query parameter) using navigation with jetpack compose: https://www.borarachar.com/groups/join?token=eyJncm91cElkIjo1NywidG9rZW5Gcm9tVXNlcklkIjozMX0=
The deeplink is being captured well by the application. The application recognizes that it should navigate to JoinGroupScreen, but the query value is not being properly returned - I always get a null value for the token within my view model when trying to get this value using the SavedStateHandle .
Here is my code:
Composable route to get the deeplink
        composable(
            route = "join_group?token={token}",
            deepLinks = listOf(
                navDeepLink {
                    uriPattern = "https://borarachar.com/groups/join?token={token}"
                    action = Intent.ACTION_VIEW
                }
            ),
            arguments = listOf(
                navArgument("token") {
                    type = NavType.StringType
                    nullable = true
                }
            )
        ) {
            JoinGroupScreen(
                navigationCallbacks = JoinGroupNavigationCallbacks(
                    goToGroupDetails = onGroupClick,
                    goToLogin = { navigate(Route.LOGIN) }
                )
            )
        }

View model
The getToken() function always returns null
@HiltViewModel
class JoinGroupViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val stateHandle: SavedStateHandle,
    private val getUserModel: GetUserModel,
    private val joinGroupUseCase: JoinGroupUseCase,
) : ViewModel() {

    private val _state: MutableStateFlow<JoinGroupUiState> =
        MutableStateFlow(JoinGroupUiState.Loading)
    val state: StateFlow<JoinGroupUiState> = _state

    private val _action: MutableSharedFlow<JoinGroupUiAction> = MutableSharedFlow()
    val action: SharedFlow<JoinGroupUiAction> = _action

    init {
        joinGroup()
    }

    fun joinGroup() {
        val token = getToken() ?: run {
            _state.update {
                JoinGroupUiState.Error(
                    message = "Failed! Token not found"
                )
            }
            return
        }
        viewModelScope.launch {
            val userId = getUserModel()?.id ?: run {
                _action.emit(JoinGroupUiAction.NavigateToLogin)
                return@launch
            }
            joinGroupUseCase(
                userId = userId,
                token = token
            ).onSuccess { groupId ->
                _action.emit(JoinGroupUiAction.NavigateToGroupDetails(groupId))
            }.onFailure { throwable ->
                _state.update {
                    JoinGroupUiState.Error(
                        message = throwable.message ?: "Error to join into the group"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private fun getToken(): String? = stateHandle.get<String>(TOKEN_KEY)

    companion object {
        private const val TOKEN_KEY = "token"
    }
}

Composable with the screen
@Composable
fun JoinGroupScreen(
    navigationCallbacks: JoinGroupNavigationCallbacks,
    viewModel: JoinGroupViewModel = hiltViewModel(),
) {

    val state by viewModel.state.collectAsStateWithLifecycle()

    ActionCollector(flow = viewModel.action) { action ->
        navigationCallbacks.run {
            when (action) {
                is JoinGroupUiAction.NavigateToGroupDetails -> goToGroupDetails(action.groupId)
                JoinGroupUiAction.NavigateToLogin -> goToLogin()
            }
        }
    }

   JoinGroupScreenContent(
       state = state,
       retry = viewModel::joinGroup
   )
}

